# MYSQL Query - List events not being blocked within a given distance

Tags: php, mysql

I have a pretty complex query which displays all events EXCEPT those where it or it's category/type/subtype are contained in a table called 'blocked'. Also, it only shows the events that are active (active=1) and the end time is between the current time and end of day.

```
SELECT e.* FROM `events` e WHERE NOT EXISTS (
       SELECT 1 FROM `blocked` b 
              WHERE b.uid = '$uid' 
          AND (e.bid = b.bid OR e.category = b.category 
               OR e.type = b.type OR e.subtype = b.subtype)) 
          AND active = '1' 
          AND end >= '$timeinfo[0]' 
          AND end <= '$timeinfo[2]'
```

Now, I've also got another query which just displays all events within a given distance. These are ordered by distance.

```
SELECT *, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians($items[3]) ) * 
            cos( radians( latitude ) ) * cos( radians( longitude ) 
            - radians($items[4]) ) + sin( radians($items[3]) ) * 
            sin( radians( latitude ) ) ) ) 
       AS distance FROM events HAVING distance < $distance 
       ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0 , $numberofhits;
```

But, now I need to combine both of these. I piddled a bit with them, but haven't gotten anything even close to working. Would it be better just to start from scratch on them?

Here's the relevant parts of the two tables:

```
EVENTS: 
  eid | bid | category | type | subtype | latitude | longitude | start | end
  001 | 00a | Nightlife | Bar | Karaoke | 33.457573 | -122.243475 | 1398686400 | 1398786400

BLOCKED: 
  uid | bid | category | type | subtype 
  001 | null | null | null | Karaoke
  001 | 00a | null | null | null
  001 | 00h | null | null | null
  002 | null | null | Bar | null
```

In the blocked table, the user 001 does not want to see anything from BIDs 00a and 00h, and also nothing with the subtype "Karaoke" (bad singing voice). Then, there is a second user 002 that just doesn't want to see anything with the type "Bar".

The display I'm after in the end is going to be all events within $distance miles of $mycoords[0], $mycoords[1] (lat/long) EXCEPT where BID/category/type/subtype are in BLOCKED for $uid, ordered by distance. I'd appreciate any help you guys could give me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to simply add your distance calculation to your 'blocked' check query, along with associated conditions.

I attempted to replicate your example data on sql fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/90bab/8 and combined them. You can modify the user id to 001 or 002 to see the different results.

For reference sake, the resulting query was

```
SELECT e.*,
  ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(-122.243475) ) * 
            cos( radians( latitude ) ) * cos( radians( longitude ) 
            - radians(33.457573) ) + sin(-122.243475) ) * 
            sin( radians( latitude ) ) )  
       AS distance
  FROM `events` e
  WHERE 
    NOT EXISTS (
       SELECT 1 FROM `blocked` b 
              WHERE b.uid = '001' 
          AND (e.bid = b.bid OR e.category = b.category 
               OR e.type = b.type OR e.subtype = b.subtype)
    ) 
    AND active = '1' 
    AND end >= 1398786400
    AND end <= 1398786400

  HAVING distance < 10000000000000;
```

**Please note** for the sake of example I had to remove your php variables and did the following

- Added some example coordinates for lat/long
- Added an example distance
- Removed the LIMIT
- Added some example times
- Added an example user id.